# Lines are not united Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I did a graph with two lines, one is on the x and y the time the speed of a medium, the second (coarse) the activity of the means: when there is speed there must be otherwise should not be drawn.

The chart is here: http://jsfiddle.net/6gdVa/ 
as you can see I made sure that the array 'date1' is a null when it should not be drawn:

```
data1.push ([Date.UTC (2014, 06, 03, 17, 10, 00), null]);
```

but unfortunately the line is not drawn, why?

Thanks to those who respond.

Dave.

Comment: Why should be there a line? Your data1 is using, in short, that data: `[value, value, null, value, null, value, null]`. So, it means you have line from first value to the second, then just two points surrounded by nulls, so line isn't drawn (because of `connectNulls` as @wergeld said). Enable markers to see what happened: http://jsfiddle.net/6gdVa/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is because, by default, null values are connected. Try setting [`connectNulls`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.connectNulls) to `true` in your series that contains `data1`.